# Google’s featured snippets

Tags: google-chrome

### Background

When I was searching `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` via Google with Google-Chrome. The **Google’s featured snippets** function gives an answer with a URL like this `https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-2/#:~:text=The%20%E2%80%9Cvalueerror%3A%20too%20many%20values,to%20iterate%20over%20a%20dictionary`. Then when I click the snippet, text in the URL param was highlighted, and automatically un-highlight on scrolling. But when I visit the URL directly, nothing happens.

I saw many URLs with the parameter-like trailing characters, `#:~:text=`.

### The question

Is there a way to control **Chrome** or other browsers to act like **Google’s featured snippets**.
Adding some thing to a URL, so webpage will do make some actions once opened. To be clear, the actions are defined by the trailing characters in the origin URL, instead of `javascript:` pseudo URL.

Also, some documentation about `#:~:text=` system (I guess it is a system) will also be appreciated

### What I did.

- Searching on google/stack overflow did not give me what I was looking for, since the symbols in `#:~:text=` were "comprehensed" as some irrelevant characters.
- Checked some google documents:

  - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/featured-snippets
  - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9351707?p=featured_snippets&hl=en-ES&visit_id=637621186733328481-586355965&rd=1

Comment: The question is answered here already.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161819/what-exactly-is-the-text-location-hash-in-an-url

Comment: Huh, then why did you ask the question? Was this an attempt at a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)? Self-answers are fine, but those are generally for questions that are _not_ already available on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I searched on Stack Overflow, and nothing poped up. Then after I redacted the question, I see the answer. So I think it's not necessary that I delete it, for the purpose of searching. So I did the self-answer, but I dont know how to mark it as [duplicated] nor [solved]. BTW, I accepted the suggestion of duplication. Thanks.