# Javascript - open new window and scroll down

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open a window and scroll down "a little" in the newly opened window.

```
function createPop(url, name)
{
  var newwindow;  
  newwindow=window.open(url,name,'width=760,height=950,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,popup=1,status=0');
  if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}

  newwindow.scrollBy(0,400);
}
```

A new window opens, but scrolling doesn't working. I tried many different ways (scrollTo ...), but nothing changed. What is wrong?

Comment: `window.focus` is a **function**, not a Boolean. Also, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus

Comment: I'm not sure. As a noob, I took an example from Github (if I remember). I thought that this line will set focus on the newly opened window. I now comment it and it still works, but "scrollBy" still doesn't.

Comment: Is the scrollbar visible? It must be. If the page is too short there will be no effect.

Comment: Yes, the scrollbar is visible.

Comment: @JanezKranjski if `newwindow` is not in your domain, you cannot scroll it. *"Blocked a frame with origin --- from accessing a cross-origin frame"*. If it *is*, than you could postMessage to the Opener Window to trigger a scroll.

Comment: Well, the URL in the new window is from one of our company's domains, but I understand (I hope) what you meant. It is not on the same domain from where the call ("window.open") was started.

Comment: Is there any way to simulate scrolling down using the keyboard? Or is this also disabled because of security reason?

Comment: No. But maybe you don't need to. Check on the target page whether there are any anchors defined at the area you need to scroll to (`<a name="xxxx">` or anything with `id="xxxx"`) and then append the hash to the URL as `#xxxx`. If not, one last option (only in Chromium-like browsers, and it comes with possibly annoying highlighting, but still) could be [linking to a text fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62162093/1871033) like Google does it.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll a newly opened page, use `onload` function. but you must use a specific condition in if statement.

In my case, I used the `windows.location.href` as a condition.

If the `location.href.includes(string added to location.href by clicking the link on the other page ) then onload scroll to (you can use link or coordinates).`

here are the steps to make it clear:

1- HTML

add `/` after `#` so the link will go to the top of the newly opened page. and we will use that as a condition

This link is on a page called work, this link will open index.html page.

```
    <a href="index.html#/work" class="nav-btn-work">WORK</a>
```

When the new page opens, there will be a `#/work` in its location.href

2- Now let's use that in javascript to scroll the newly opened page:

```
    let pageUrl = window.location.href;
    
    if (pageUrl.includes("#/work")) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        location.href = "#work"; 
      }, 500);
    }

// #work is a section in the middle of the new page and after opening the new page, it will scroll to it.
```

I waited for half a second before scrolling. you can change or remove that.

I hope this helps. it works for me with no errors or problems.