# JavaScript - Get fragment value after Scroll To Text Hash Fragment '#:~:text=' from a URL

Tags: javascript, url, anchor, url-fragment

Using JavaScript how can the content after #:~:text= in the URL be obtained?

#:~:text= is used to [Scroll To Text Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62161819/what-exactly-is-the-text-location-hash-in-an-url).

I would have expected the [Get fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317508/get-fragment-value-after-hash-from-a-url) method to work, but it does not.

Comment: You can't get this. This highlight marker is used internally by Chrome, it's not exposed to the page itself.

Comment: @Barmar I think your correct, that might be the current answer, hopefully that changes in the future

Comment: I've linked to a question that answers how to access it.